# Flakey debug behavior in application start, global.asax

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7

Not using Cassini, but IIS7 to run an ASP.NET app.

The debug behavior is flakey.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I was able to step into the application start event in global.asax but sometimes I can't.

Sometimes VS2008 opens the published global.asax so I have two instances of global.asax opened in VS, the source and the published.

I reset the AppDomain and IIS and I can't put my finger on why this is happening.  Any clues?

To add, while it won't go into application start, I have an OnChangeEventHandler event - it does step into the event handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't connect to w3wp.exe soon enough to handle breakpoints in Application_Start for IIS7-hosted applications. To debug, use the following line to call debugger explicitly,

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

and choose to launch a new instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks. Any other practical iis7 gotchas like this?

Comment: for the love of god. i wonder how many hours were lost because of this!

Answer (score 0):

make a change in the web.config, the application pool will recycle and the global.asax code will be loaded, the debugger should still be attached